# Write ndarray with strings in first row followed by a matrix of numbers

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

Let's say that I create a big matrix with np.vstack with a vector of strings as a first row followed by a matrix with numbers. How can I save/write in to a file? and in a nice aligned way?

Simplifying:

```
names = np.array(['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3'])
floats = np.array([ 0.1234 ,  0.5678 ,  0.9123 ])

# 1) In order to vstack them, do I need to expand dimensions?

np.expand_dims(floats, axis=0)
np.expand_dims(names, axis=0)

Output = np.vstack((names,floats)) # so I get the following matrix
    NAME_1   NAME_2  NAME_3
    0.1234  0.5678   0.9123

# 2) How can a save/print into a file being able to modify the format of the numbers? 
# And keep the columns aligned? 
# Something like this: (taking into account that I have a lot of columns)
    NAME_1    NAME_2    NAME_3
    1.23e-1  5.67e-1    9.12e-1
# I tryied with:
np.savetxt('test.txt',  Matrix, fmt=' %- 1.8s' , delimiter='\t')

# But I can't change the format of the numbers.
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Don't mix strings and numbers in an array. First write `names`, then write `floats` with the appropriate format.

Comment: How would you do that appending the matrix after the first line? Thanks!

Comment: Open the file with `f = open('test.txt')`. Then pass `f` instead of the filename to `np.savetxt`. Call `np.savetxt` twice - once for `headers` and once for `floats`. Finally, close the file with `f.close()`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I found a solution following the kazemakase comments. It feels quite inefficient for big matrices but it does the work:

```
names  = np.array(['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3'])
floats = np.array([[ 0.1234 ,  0.5678 ,  0.9123 ],
                  [ 0.1234 ,  -0.5678 ,  0.9123 ]])

with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for i in range(names.shape[0]) :
        f.write( '{:^15}'.format(names[i]))
    f.write( '{}'.format('\n'))   

    for i in range(floats.shape[0]) :
        for j in range(floats.shape[1]) :
            f.write( '{:^ 15.4e}'.format(floats[i,j]))
        f.write( '{}'.format('\n'))
```

Giving the desired output:

```
    NAME_1         NAME_2         NAME_3     
   1.2340e-01     5.6780e-01     9.1230e-01  
   1.2340e-01    -5.6780e-01     9.1230e-01
```

Thank you!

Comment: That is not exactly what I had in mind but I am happy you found a way. Don't worry about efficiency unless it actually becomes too slow. (Tip: you can write `f.write('\n')` to generate a newline. No need to use `format` for that.)

Answer (score 0):

`savetxt` takes a `header` parameter.

```
In [3]: header = '   '.join(names)
In [4]: header
Out[4]: 'NAME_1   NAME_2   NAME_3'
In [5]: np.savetxt('test.txt', floats, fmt='%15.4e', header=header)
In [6]: cat test.txt
# NAME_1   NAME_2   NAME_3
     1.2340e-01      5.6780e-01      9.1230e-01
     1.2340e-01     -5.6780e-01      9.1230e-01
```

This puts the floats in the right columns; the header formatting needs tweaking.

If you go the `vstack` route, you get an array of strings.

```
In [7]: np.vstack((names, floats))
Out[7]: 
array([['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3'],
       ['0.1234', '0.5678', '0.9123'],
       ['0.1234', '-0.5678', '0.9123']], 
      dtype='<U32')
```

That can be written with `savetxt`, but you have to use the `%15s` kind of format.

As for efficiency, `savetxt` works like your answer, except that it formats and writes a whole row at a time.  My `savetxt` call does, effectively:

```
fmt = ''.join(['%15.4e']*3)+'\n'
f = open(file, 'wb')
f.write(header); f.write('\nl')
for row in floats:
   f.write( fmt % tuple(row)) 

In [9]: fmt=''.join(['%15.4e']*3)
In [10]: print(fmt%tuple(floats[0]))
     1.2340e-01     5.6780e-01     9.1230e-01
```

Comment: Thanks hpaulj! That's what I saw when using savetxt, one can use it only with the %15 kind of format, so the solution seems to be either to format the numbers before using the vstack or to use f.write without vstack and writing element by element.